# How to compress a TMPFS folder?

Tags: compression, tmpfs

I'm looking for a way to compress a tmpfs folder on the fly. I would like to use it for a local cache folder with a lot of data. I know there is a way to use Redis with eg LZF compression, but I prefer to use tmpfs.

Comment: [Zram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) doesn't do exactly this, but may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could mount a **compressing filesystem** on top of the tmpfs.

If it would be still maintained, `fusecompress` would fit the purpose well.

Unfortunately it seems to be outdated, so we need another implementation (it may be better to not use a FUSE-based filesystem for performance reasons anyway):

It seems that both `Btrfs` and `ZFS` should work - but I can not give detailed advice for using them.

There are certainly other filesystems that could work, but it's not trivial to see which solutions have suitable features. [e2compr](http://e2compr.sourceforge.net/) compresses files, but not directories, for example. Depending on your usage, you may need compressed directories. Many compressed filesystems are ruled out because they are read-only (eg. `squashfs`), targeted at applications like booting an embedded device, or a live desktop session, from a static image.

The critical point is the performance. Whether it's fast enough depends on your needs, and the implementation - you will need to test.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I have been using [zram-generator](https://github.com/systemd/zram-generator#readme) to create `zstd` compressed directories for kernel building. At the moment I `remount -o rw,noatime,discard,nodev,nosuid /zram/mountpoint` but this functionality should be [included soon](https://github.com/systemd/zram-generator/pull/90) as `mount-option`.

```
[~/build]$ zramctl
NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA  COMPR  TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram2 zstd          5.9G  1.3G   1.3G   1.3G      16 /var/build/sources
/dev/zram1 zstd           15G  1.2G 289.1M 302.9M      16 /var/build/makepkg
/dev/zram0 zstd            3G  9.1M   8.3M   8.7M      16 [SWAP]
```

Comment: The issues is closed now, mount options are there in `zram-generator` 